# How to properly purge HBase META table from rows without region info?

Tags: nosql, hbase, metadata

I have HBase META table which contains some records about already deleted table regions. That rows do not contain region info so nothing really harmful but anyway it is not so good.

Of course I can just manually delete appropriate rows but maybe there is some ready to use tool or 'best practice' approach? I have tried `hbase hbck` and `hbase hbck -fixMeta` ... all of them see this situation as normal and don't make any correction but when I'm checking region locations using API HBase outputs lot of warnings about records in META which do not have embedded region info which is actually true.

HBase 0.94.6 is used (Cloudera CDH 4.4).
Any automatic solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended with offline repair tool:

`hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.hbck.OfflineMetaRepair`

It fixed all my problems for now but I'd like to see other options.